# Size of input and submit button in percent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set size of button and edit in percent

```
<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
    <input type="text" name="input" style="width: 90%; margin-bottom: 5px;height: 30px;" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" style="width: 90%;height:30px;" />
</div>
```

But linear size of this is differnce. Why?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: they have default paddings added to them, make the padding 0 or add box-sizing ^^^

Comment: @Dmitry: in future HTML/CSS specific questions, try to remove JSF noise from the question. This improves chance on answers from HTML/CSS adepts who have generally no idea how the JSF-generated HTML output look like. After all, JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator and therefore completely irrelevant to the problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using "plain HTML" or even some PHP/ASP/etc code which produces exactly the same HTML. Once you get the answer, just rewrite your JSF code as such that it produces exactly the desired HTML output.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza i except that height and width of the button and inputText will be the same, but it's not true.

Comment: Ya for sake of easy math lets assume the browser is 1000px wide, at 90% the width should be 900px. However like I mentioned above there are PADDINGS applied to your input. Padding will ADD to your width if box-sizing is not applied. So if you are setting the width to 90% but have a padding-left of 5% (50px in this example) the total width will be 90%(900) + 5%(50) = 950px, thus confusing you. Simply add box-sizing to your elements or set padding to 0. Use chrome dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem here is with the property `box-sizing`. For default the `input type="submit"` has this:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

That makes the border be inside the defined `width:90%`. On the other side the  `input type="text"` doesn't have the property and the border is outside increasing the final `width`.

This should solve the problem:

```
input {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  /*Safari/Chrome*/
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  /*Firefox*/
  box-sizing:border-box;  
}
```

<sub>Don't forget the prefixes to make it work on all browsers</sub>

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/VY7Nn/10/**

Comment: @BalusC I'm using firefox 25.0.1 and it doesnt work, but in the google chrome 31.0.1650.57 m it works correctly. I.m confused. How it is possible that in the different browser we have the different result? In my firefox padding:0 has some effect but not correctly full: [link](http://i60.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1204/e3/763832b52d576653c797f0cb1808b9e3.png).

Comment: ok then try with the prefix vendor check my edit and fiddle edited

Comment: @Dmitry: Check the example in the link in my comment on your Q.